# ansible unarchieve is very unstable

Tags: ansible

We are using ansible to install wso2api manager and wso2 identity server in remote instanes of AWS.

unarchive is working fine with wso2is-5.1.0.zip and throwing error while using wso2am-1.10.0.zip.

below is the command for unarchive which I have used

```
- name: unarchive wso2is-5.1.0.zip 
  unarchive: src="{{wso2_dest}}/wso2is-5.1.0.zip" dest="{{wso2_dest}}" copy=no

- name: unarchive apim
  unarchive: src="{{wso2_dest}}/wso2am-1.10.0.zip" dest="{{wso2_dest}}" copy=no
```

(or)

```
command: "unzip {{wso2_dest}}/wso2am-1.10.0.zip -d {{wso2_dest}}"
```

In apim extraction both are throwing errors.. sometimes it will work and sometimes not.

So, currently I planned to use tar command for extraction.

```
- name: unarchive apim
  command: "tar -xf {{wso2_dest}}/wso2am-1.10.0.tar"
```

this is working fine.

I want to know why unarchive is so unable.

### Error log for unzip:

> TASK [WSO2_APIM: unarchive apim] *******************************
>   fatal: [ip]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["unzip", "/x/y/apim_mysql/wso2am-1.10.0.zip", "-d", "/x/y/apim_mysql"], "delta": "0:00:00.226518", "end": "2016-11-21 10:48:13.171464", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2016-11-21 10:48:12.944946", "stderr": "replace /x/y/apim_mysql/wso2am-1.10.0/repository/axis2/client/lib/bcprov-jdk15.jar? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL\n(EOF or read error, treating as \"[N]one\" ...)", "stdout": "Archive:  /home/ubuntu/apim_mysql/wso2am-1.10.0.zip", "stdout_lines": ["Archive:  /home/ubuntu/apim_mysql/wso2am-1.10.0.zip"], "warnings": ["Consider using unarchive module rather than running unzip"]}

### Error log for unarchieve module :

> wso2am-1.10.0/dbscripts/metrics/mysql.sql -d /home/ubuntu/apim_mysql01", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 7] Argument list too long", "rc": 7}

last lines are pasted for unarchive module.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra_opts method in unarchive module in ansible. For more information please follow this documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html

```
- name: unarchive wso2is-5.1.0.zip 
  unarchive:
    extra_opts: -j 
    src: "{{wso2_dest}}/wso2is-5.1.0.zip"
    dest: "{{wso2_dest}}"
    remote_src: yes
```

`remote_src: yes` --> This will allow you to source a zip file from remote server.

`extra_opts: -j` -->
`-j` is used to store unzipped files in current working directory without creating a new directory.

In `extra_ops` we can use any option tags used in unzip command in linux.

For the list of options in unzip command in linux refer this: https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip

Answer (score 0):

It seems that unarchive [should be fixed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3810) for ansible >= 2.1.3.0

The unzip variant [cannot be fixed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/commit/c776932ca360342a0a073ef7b8a78f7a56d774fa).

Answer (score 0):

This is [bug known for `unarchive` module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3810).

For unzip, you can add `-o` option to overwrite files WITHOUT prompting.

```
command: "unzip -o {{wso2_dest}}/wso2am-1.10.0.zip -d {{wso2_dest}}"
```